# How to delete unnecessary dot?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(10,10)
\psset{unit=2cm,PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
\pstTriangle(0,4){C}(0,0){A}(3,0){B} 
 %%% OR \pstTriangle[PointSymbol=none](0,4){C}(0,0){A}(3,0){B} 
\pstMiddleAB{A}{B}{I1} \pstArcOAB{I1}{A}{B}
\pstMiddleAB{B}{C}{I2} \pstArcOAB{I2}{B}{C}
\pstMiddleAB{C}{A}{I3} \pstArcOAB{I3}{C}{A}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
\pstTriangle[PointSymbol=none,%% <<---
linecolor=blue,linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth](1.5,-1){A}(0,1){B}(-1,-.5){C}
\pstTriangleIC[linecolor=red]{A}{B}{C}
\pstTriangleOC[linecolor=red]{A}{B}{C}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none,PosAngle={0,90,180}](1.5,-1){A}(0,1){B}(-1,-.5){C}
\pspolygon[linejoin=2](A)(B)(C)
\pstTriangleIC[linecolor=red]{A}{B}{C}
\pstTriangleOC[linecolor=red]{A}{B}{C}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A new problem.

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=3cm}
\begin{pspicture}(2,2)

%{\psset{PointSymbolA=none,PointSymbolB=none,PointName=none}
{
     \psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
     \pstGeonode(0,0){A}(1,0){B}(1,1){C}(0,1){D}
     \pswedge[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](C){1}{135}{-45}
     \pstTranslation{D}{B}{C}[C1] % phep tinh tien
     \pstTranslation{B}{D}{C}[C2]
     \pstInterLC{C1}{C2}{C}{B}{M1}{M2} % giao diem duong tron va duong thang
     \pstInterLC{A}{C1}{A}{M1}{M3}{M4}
     \pstInterLC{A}{C2}{A}{M2}{M5}{M6}
     %\psGetDistanceAB(A)(M2){MW} get 1.73205
     \psarc(A){1.73205}{0}{90}
     \psline(M6)(A)(M4)
       }
     \psdot*(1,1)
     \end{pspicture}
     \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

```
 \documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage{pst-eucl}

 \begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(10,10)
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none,PointName={B,C,none},PosAngle={-110,-80}](0,0){B}(7,0){C}(-1,0){Z}(5,0){Y}
\pstInterCC[PointSymbol=none,PosAngleA=90]{B}{Y}{C}{Z}{A}{M2} %%<<<---
\pspolygon(B)(A)(C)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

With ver 1.61 it produces:

[image]

With ver 1.63 it produces:

[image]

Comment: @jfbu, the OP refers to the black bullet indicating the intersection.

Comment: The Section 3.6 from `pst-eucl` documentation shows the same problem. Looks like a bug?

Comment: One way it to pass `none` to each point: `\pstTriangle[PointSymbolC=none,PointSymbolA=none,PointSymbolB=none](0,4){C}(0,0){A}(3,0){B}`

Comment: @jfbu I edited my question...

Comment: So, you have to use both `PointSymbol=none,PointSymbolA=none` but I don't know why. Maybe, as I said, a bug.

Comment: It seems the problem comes from using the key `PosAngle={...,...,...}`: I tried reproduce the figure using `\psGeonode`, then `\pspolygon(A)(B)(C)`. No dot until  I  use `PosAngle`.

Comment: @Bernard I do not understand your comment. See edited question.

Comment: @chishimotoji: I don't understand myself: I did have a bullet with  `PosAngle`, and didn't have it wthout this key. Now I don't have it anymore, like you. Perhaps there was some typo in my initial code, which has been removed unadvertently since then…

Comment: Only the first point in the list of the three for the triangle has to be set additionally to none: `PointSymbolA=none`. And it makes no difference if your first point is named C

Comment: @Herbert See edited question. How do you think about it?....

Comment: try 1.64, available from http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/tex/generic/pst-eucl/

Comment: @Herbert You can try \pstInterCC[PointSymbolA=none,PosAngleA=90,PosAngleB=65]{B}{Y}{C}{Z}{A}{M2} **or**  \pstInterCC[PointSymbolB=none,PosAngleA=90,PosAngleB=65]{B}{Y}{C}{Z}{A}{M2} **or** \pstInterCC[PosAngleA=90,PosAngleB=65]{B}{Y}{C}{Z}{A}{M2}

Comment: cannot see a problem with 1.64

Comment: @Herbert So, PointSymbolA and PointSymbolB with value none are not validated within \pstInterCC....

Comment: I see. Try again with 1.65a

Comment: @Herbert yes, I loaded \pstInterCC normally....

Comment: Does it work or not??

Comment: @Herbert Yes, of course. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit** (based on @chishimotoji's comment)

Only `PointSymbolA=none` is enough to delete the black bullet.

But, that is strange to me since the bullet is at point `C` in coordinates `(0,8)` (note the change of units).

---

Pass the options `PointSymbolA=none` (and for other 2 points) to the `\pstTriangle` command.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(10,10)
\psset{unit=2cm,PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
\pstTriangle[%
  PointSymbolC=none,
  PointSymbolA=none,
  PointSymbolB=none
](0,4){C}(0,0){A}(3,0){B}
 %%% OR \pstTriangle[PointSymbol=none](0,4){C}(0,0){A}(3,0){B} 
\pstMiddleAB{A}{B}{I1} \pstArcOAB{I1}{A}{B}
\pstMiddleAB{B}{C}{I2} \pstArcOAB{I2}{B}{C}
\pstMiddleAB{C}{A}{I3} \pstArcOAB{I3}{C}{A}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: PointSymbolA=none, position " A " PointSymbolC=none, PointSymbolB=none are unnecessary... :-)

Comment: @chishimotoji, sorry. Could write it better? I wrote 3 lines of codes. Are you saying that only one is needed?

Comment: Oh no, I think there is a problem with the first position of \pstTriangle[Options](){A}...

Comment: @chishimotoji, I edited.

Answer (score 3):

With version 1.63, available from http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/tex/generic/pst-eucl/  or in the next two days with an update of the TeXLive or MikTeX:

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none,PosAngle={0,90,180}](1.5,-1){A}(0,1){B}(-1,-.5){C}
\pspolygon[linejoin=2](A)(B)(C)
\pstTriangleIC[linecolor=red]{A}{B}{C}
\pstTriangleOC[linecolor=red]{A}{B}{C}
\end{pspicture}


\psset{unit=3cm}

\begin{pspicture}(2,2)
    \psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
    \pstGeonode(0,0){A}(1,0){B}(1,1){C}(0,1){D}
    \pswedge[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](C){1}{135}{-45}
    \pstTranslation[PointSymbol=none]{D}{B}{C}[C1] 
    \pstTranslation[PointSymbol=none]{B}{D}{C}[C2]
    \pstInterLC[PointSymbol=none]{C1}{C2}{C}{B}{M1}{M2}
    \pstInterLC[PointSymbol=none]{A}{C1}{A}{M1}{M3}{M4}
    \pstInterLC[PointSymbol=none]{A}{C2}{A}{M2}{M5}{M6}
    \psarc(A){1.73205}{0}{90}
    \psline(M6)(A)(M4)
    \psdot*(C)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please see edited question. Label A is lost.